# Generate SWT token, and sign it, from IClaimsPrincipal

Tags: claims-based-identity, windows-identity, simple-web-token

I would like to create a SWT token based on the claims in:

```
IClaimsPrincipal principal = (IClaimsPrincipal)User;
IClaimsIdentity identity = (IClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
```

I have found code for validating a swt token, but haven't been able to find a sample that creates one from IClaimsIdentity claims.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my blog it that is of any help to you... http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/anatomy-of-a-simple-web-token-swt/